TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'ctime' of object '#<Stats>'
I have a simple gulp file setup that compiles scss to css and then continues to watch for changes during development, I am developing an electron app based on node (v22.0.0)
It was working before when my node is in LTS (^20.0.0) then I updated it to 22 when I got this error
[10:01:24] Using gulpfile D:\location\to\gulp\file\js\gulpfile.js
[10:01:24] Starting 'default'...
[10:01:24] Starting 'styles'...
[10:01:24] 'styles' errored after 218 ms
[10:01:24] TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'ctime' of object '#<Stats>'
    at filePush (D:\location\to\node_modules\gulp-sass\index.js:62:57)
    at D:\location\to\node_modules\gulp-sass\index.js:151:9
    at Function.call$2 (D:\location\to\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:118543:16)
    at render_closure0.call$1 (D:\location\to\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:101932:21)
    at _RootZone.runUnary$2$2 (D:\location\to\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:37656:18)
    at _Future__propagateToListeners_handleValueCallback.call$0 (D:\location\to\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:36474:51)
    at Object._Future__propagateToListeners (D:\location\to\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:5132:93)
    at _Future._completeWithValue$1 (D:\location\to\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:36338:9)
    at _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete$1 (D:\location\to\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:35953:14)
    at Object._asyncReturn (D:\location\to\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:4918:17)
[10:01:24] 'default' errored after 226 ms

gulpfile.js:
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));

function styles() {
  return gulp.src('../app/renderer/static/scss/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../app/renderer/static/css'));
}

function watch() {
  gulp.watch('../app/renderer/static/scss/**/*.scss', styles);
}

exports.styles = styles;
exports.watch = watch;
exports.default = gulp.series(styles, watch);

DevDeps:
    "gulp": "^5.0.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^5.1.0"
    "sass": "^1.76.0",

What I have done:
- reinstalled my deps using node cache clear --force then running npm i again
- updated the packages mentioned which is gulp gulp-sass sass using npm i --save-dev <package-name>
- tested in isolation but still no good, I removed codes that might possible cause the error but to no avail
- reviewed recent changes but I have no significant changes other than upgrading node to v22
I tried the fixes aforementioned above still to no avail

I see from gulp-sass/index.js that there is file.stat.ctime = new Date();, which doesn't work in Node 22.0.0

ohh I see, what can be done about it? I understand that downgrading to Node LTS 20.12.2 is a much easier approach but I consider using Node 22.0.0.

Node 22.1.0 is out, and you can now assign to the ctime property. So you can upgrade to 22.1.0 and check if it works.

It worked after upgrading to 22.1.0

У меня была такая же проблема, но с yarn
Что я предприня, чтобы решить данную проблему
Удалил .pnp* файлы
rm -rf .pnp.*

и после этого создать файл .yarnrc.yml с
nodeLinker: node-modules


теперь можно снова всё устанавливать
yarn

